# Change pandas series type from str to list/numeric

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

`df_small`
[image]

Each column is of type `pandas.Series` and each value inside a column is of type `str`.

```py
df_small['center'][0] # '[(181, 186)]'
```

I want to remove the string quotations from each value to access the list values.

Comment: Does `pd.to_numeric(df_small['center'], errors='coerce')`  work for you?

Comment: use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). it will convert the string representation of list to actual list

Comment: please provide a sample of your dataframe as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested per comments, you can use `literal_eval` from the ast module, some documentation can be found here. I would use `map(lambda x:)` for this scenario, in case not all values are `list` as perhaps suggested in the title:

```
import ast
df['center'] = df['center'].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```